# Google Maps Geocoding Result Order

Tags: php, json, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps Geocoding API to send partial addresses and receive full address info.

Google's API is inconsistent in how it returns results based on the data it's able to match given the partial address, specifically the number of objects within the "address_components" field (ex: sometimes it wont include 'administrative_area_level_2', in this case 'Kings County').

Is there a way for me to retrieve specific 'address_component' data using the "types" field as the identifier? Otherwise, it seems I have to perform a large series of manual checks to determine how many address_components Google has returned, and which exactly those are.

The portion of the JSON response I am interested in is:

```
{
"results":[  
  {  
     "address_components":[  
        {  
           "long_name":"125",
           "short_name":"125",
           "types":[  
              "street_number"
           ]
        },
        {  
           "long_name":"Court Street",
           "short_name":"Court St",
           "types":[  
              "route"
           ]
        },
        {  
           "long_name":"Brooklyn",
           "short_name":"Brooklyn",
           "types":[  
              "political",
              "sublocality",
              "sublocality_level_1"
           ]
        },
        {  
           "long_name":"Kings County",
           "short_name":"Kings County",
           "types":[  
              "administrative_area_level_2",
              "political"
           ]
        },
        {  
           "long_name":"New York",
           "short_name":"NY",
           "types":[  
              "administrative_area_level_1",
              "political"
           ]
        },
        {  
           "long_name":"United States",
           "short_name":"US",
           "types":[  
              "country",
              "political"
           ]
        },
        {  
           "long_name":"11201",
           "short_name":"11201",
           "types":[  
              "postal_code"
           ]
        }
     ],
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$addr = json_decode('{json here..}', true);


/**
 * @param string $name
 * @param string $type
 * @param array  $from
 * @return string|array|null
 */
function getByType($name, $type, array $from)
{
    foreach($from as $values) {
        if (in_array($type, $values['types'])) {
            return $values[$name] ?: $values;
        }
    }

    return null;
}


var_dump(getByType('long_name', 'route', $addr['results'][0]['address_components']));
```

[3v4l](https://3v4l.org/fp4Av) here

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function to retrieve the component object given a type. Something like this:

```
$components = ...; // The JSON decoded "address_components" array

/**
 * Get a component by type.
 *
 * @param  {string} $type The component type. E.g. 'street_number'.
 * @return {null|object} The desired component or null in case there's no
 *                       component for the given type.
 */
$componentByType = function ($type) use ($components) {
    $found = array_filter($components, function ($component) use ($type) {
        return in_array($type, $component->types);
    });
    return reset($found);
};
```

Using the response from your question, the following code ...

```
$component = $componentByType('route');
echo $component->long_name;
```

... would output:

> Court Street